# Implementing Cocoa XML-RPC framework for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xml-rpc

I have my drupal xml-rpc service setup, and now I want to retrieve content for my iphone app.

I'm attempting to use https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc, however I dont know where to begin. How do I add the project to my own project for use? I've added a static library before; is it the same process? Just drag the proj file to my project and add the xml-rpc library?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dragging the project file for xmlrpc framework into the code list in XCode for starters.  Next make the framework target in the xmlrpc framework a build dependency.  Finally add the xmlrpc.framework to your linked frameworks.  Exactly how you do this depends on whether you are using XCode 3 or 4